# Getting an error with trying to set up Firebase push Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I am following the Firebase Push Notifications quick start but am receiving this error.

[image]

Not sure what's going on as this is the documentation for the quick start guide.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set your `AppDelegate` as a `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`, but your `AppDelegate` does not implement that protocol yet. Find out more information about protocols [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html). The spec for `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate). Something like this will work:

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    optional func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
        willPresent notification: UNNotification, 
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
            // TODO: Implement
    }

    optional func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
        didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, 
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
            // TODO: Implement
    }
}
```

The second error means the property does not exist. The documentation is most likely out of date with the framework.

Comment: So your solution solved the first problem with the delegate, but FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self is not working. It say's the same error as above. It say's it is supposed to work for Swift 3, so that's just strange.

Comment: I've got Firebase in my Swift 3 app, and I can't find any reference in the framework to a delegate on FIRMessaging.messaging(). They might have refactored the API to not require a delegate. I'd just remove that line.